# FindFit for implicit functions - mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, implicit, test-data

I would like to fit some test data into some implicit function.

I would like to fit a few parameters to an eliptical equation f(x,y)=a where a is a known variable. My test data and the function are more complex, however I got more data points than variables. It is kind of not possible to convert the equation that I want to fit into an explicit form like f(x)=y Therefore I attached some code to get the basic idea.

```
Test = {{0, 1}, {0.1, 0.9}, {1.1, 0}};

Ftest = a*x^2 + b*y^2

FindFit[Test, Ftest == 2, {a, b}, {x, y}];
```

However this leads to an error: Number of coordinates (1) is not equal to the number of variables \
(2). >>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pose this as a least squares minimization:

```
data = {{0, 1}, {0.1, 0.9}, {1.1, 0}}
Ftest[x_, y_] := a*x^2 + b*y^2
fit = FindMinimum[ Total[(Ftest @@@ data - 2)^2] , {a, b}] 
ContourPlot[ (Ftest[x, y] /. fit[[2]]) == 2 , {x, 0, 1.5}, {y, 0, 
  1.5}, Epilog -> {Red, Point /@ data}]
```

[image]

to use fit functions you need to solve for y and you end up with:

```
fit = NonlinearModelFit[data, Sqrt[2 - a*x^2]/Sqrt[b], {a, b}, x]

Plot[fit[x], {x, 0, 1.2}, Epilog -> {Red, Point /@ data}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]